# object Object in string after using Array.split, Array.filer and Array.map to format string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm writing a function that takes a string, searches for emojis to keywords by converting the string to an array using the `.split` method, the function then does a look up on the emoji value against the array values and when it finds a match it returns a string. When all is done we `.join` our array to create a string.

So take, for example the current string with emojis (I get this from a user input):

> I like rock and roll

In my component the string above is `this.message`, here's my code:

```
 emojiLookup() {

    let splitMessage = this.message.split(/([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g);

    this.message = splitMessage.map((a) => {
       if(this.isItemEmoji(a)) {

           return this.emojiList.filter((em) => { // this.emojiList is an array list to match the emoji value to a keyword
               if(this.emojiToUnicode(a) === em.unicode) {
                   return (em.aliases[0]); // this value is a string e.g. 'smile'
               }
           });

       } else {
           return a;
       }
    }).join('');

    console.log(this.message);
}

this.emojiLookup(this.message);

// helper methods used abive
isItemEmoji(s:string) {
    return /\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDE4F]/g.test(s);
}

emojiToUnicode(emoji: any) {
    if(emoji){
        return '\\u' + emoji.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + '\\u' + emoji.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);
    }
}
```

Now all seems to be working however when I output my converted `this.message` I get the following:

```
I like ro[object Object]ck and roll [object Object][object Object]
```

I haven't a clue why `[object Object]` is appearing rather than the string I return from `return (em.aliases[0])`? I have checked the value of `return (em.aliases[0])` and it is always a string... what am I doing wrong?

I am using TypeScript in my Angular2 Application. lodash is available too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter()` method returns an array of elements that match the filter; you're treating it as though it would return a single element.

So where you expect `filter` to return `'smile'` it is instead returning `['smile']`.  And join is stringifying that as `[object Object]`.

If you're sure you'll always find exactly one match in the array, you can stick a `[0]` at the end of the `filter` call (`filter(...)[0]`)... but then if you'll always find exactly one match, why use `filter`?

If you might get 0 or multiple matches, I think you could `join()` what `filter` returns, and then return that result for your final `join()` of the overall string.

Comment: Ahh!!! My god! You're right! I don't need the filter! What was I thinking?